# Creating android app, say mother app

Tags: android, air, adobe

I'm new to this forum..
I want to create a Android app (say mother app), which can be installed to the Android devices on the home menu. This app should contains one or more apps inside (say child app)..

The mother app should have online login verification and on the successful login this app should show all the child app...

The concept is just like creating a app such as newsstand of iPhone.

Is it possible to create such app for Android using Adobe Air

When any child app is installed from the marketplace then It must be shown inside mother app instead of home menu

To make it clear:
I want to create a app which store my other apps when it is downloaded from anywhere, instead of placing my apps here and there on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try out [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) first and proceed further. It will surely help you out. You can check this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889466/using-adobe-air-to-develop-android-mobile-applications) for information about using `Adobe Air` in your application. I can help you with this information only. :D